# Printing the DOM tree of a HTML code in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to print out the DOM tree of the HTML code written in the textarea by the user but I can't print out the code typed in textarea.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> HTML Tree Structure </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      function traverseDOMTree(targetDocument, currentElement, depth) {
        if (currentElement) {
          var j;
          var tagName = currentElement.tagName;
          // Prints the node tagName, such as <A>, <IMG>, etc
          if (tagName)
            targetDocument.writeln("&lt;"+currentElement.tagName+"&gt;");
          else
            targetDocument.writeln("[unknown tag]");

          // Traverse the tree
          var i = 0;
          var currentElementChild = currentElement.childNodes[i];
          while (currentElementChild) {
            // Formatting code (indent the tree so it looks nice on the screen)
            targetDocument.write("<BR>\n");
            for (j = 0; j < depth; j++) {
              // &#166 is just a vertical line
              targetDocument.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&#166");
            }               
            targetDocument.writeln("<BR>");
            for (j = 0; j < depth; j++) {
              targetDocument.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&#166");
            }         
            if (tagName)
              targetDocument.write("--");

            // Recursively traverse the tree structure of the child node
            traverseDOMTree(targetDocument, currentElementChild, depth+1);
            i++;
            currentElementChild=currentElement.childNodes[i];
          }
          // The remaining code is mostly for formatting the tree
          targetDocument.writeln("<BR>");
          for (j = 0; j < depth - 1; j++) {
            targetDocument.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&#166");
          }     
          targetDocument.writeln("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
          if (tagName)
            targetDocument.writeln("&lt;/"+tagName+"&gt;");
        }
      }

      function printDOMTree(domElement, destinationWindow) {
        var outputWindow = destinationWindow;
        if (!outputWindow)
          outputWindow = window.open();

        outputWindow.document.open("text/html", "replace");
        outputWindow.document.write("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>DOM</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n");
        outputWindow.document.write("<CODE>\n");
        traverseDOMTree(outputWindow.document, domElement, 1);
        outputWindow.document.write("</CODE>\n");
        outputWindow.document.write("</BODY></HTML>\n");

        outputWindow.document.close();
      }  
    </SCRIPT>
    <DIV ID="myDiv">
      <form>
        <textarea name="htmlcode" id="htmlCode"
            style="width: 400px; height: 100px">
        </textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Show me the DOM Tree"
            onClick="javascript=printDOMTree(document.getElementById('htmlCode')); return true;" />
        <br/> 
      </form>
    </DIV>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't get the input button and `printDOMTree` function to work with reading what's typed by the user into the `textarea`. What's wrong with the HTML part of my code? How can I improve it and make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `printDOMTree` function is receiving a `textarea` element whose `value` property is a string containing HTML text. Before sending this element into your `traverseDOMTree` function, you need to convert it to a DOM element.

```
// inside printDOMTree
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerHTML = domElement.value;
traverseDOMTree(outputWindow.document, node.firstChild, 1);
```

Comment: I did test the code that you've edited, it seems that some issues have been fixed but still its not printing the DOM tree of any html code that is written in the textarea, it just says unknown tag.
Its not reading the value of the textarea which user types.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wimplash/5Ev6F/). You may still need to take care of things like text nodes and you may want to tweak the formatting again.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the main problems with your code:

You don't need `javascript=` in the `onclick` attribute. Not sure if having this will break your code but you should remove it.

You are passing the value of the text area to it, but you need to parse it as HTML before you can use it as a DOM. Please give this a try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Tree Structure </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    // <![CDATA[
        function traverseDOMTree(targetDocument, currentElement, depth) {
            if (currentElement) {
                var j;
                var tagName = currentElement.nodeName;
                // Prints the node tagName, such as <A>, <IMG>, etc
                if (tagName)
                    targetDocument.writeln("&lt;" + tagName + "&gt;");
                else
                    targetDocument.writeln("[unknown tag]");

                // Traverse the tree
                var i = 0;
                var currentElementChild = currentElement.childNodes[i];
                while (currentElementChild) {
                    // Formatting code (indent the tree so it looks nice on the screen)
                    targetDocument.write("<BR>\n");
                    for (j = 0; j < depth; j++) {
                        // &#166 is just a vertical line
                        targetDocument.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&#166");
                    }
                    targetDocument.writeln("<BR>");
                    for (j = 0; j < depth; j++) {
                        targetDocument.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&#166");
                    }
                    if (tagName)
                        targetDocument.write("--");

                    // Recursively traverse the tree structure of the child node
                    traverseDOMTree(targetDocument, currentElementChild, depth + 1);
                    i++;
                    currentElementChild = currentElement.childNodes[i];
                }
                // The remaining code is mostly for formatting the tree
                targetDocument.writeln("<BR>");
                for (j = 0; j < depth - 1; j++) {
                    targetDocument.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&#166");
                }
                targetDocument.writeln("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                if (tagName)
                    targetDocument.writeln("&lt;/" + tagName + "&gt;");
            }
        }

        function printDOMTree(domElement, destinationWindow) {
            var outputWindow = destinationWindow, content, e, i;

            if (!outputWindow) {
                outputWindow = window.open();
            }

            try {
                content = $.parseHTML(domElement.value);
            } catch (e) {
                alert("The value could not be parsed as HTML.");
                return;
            }

            outputWindow.document.open("text/html", "replace");
            outputWindow.document.write("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>DOM</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n");
            outputWindow.document.write("<CODE>\n");
            for (i = 0; i < content.length; i += 1) {
                traverseDOMTree(outputWindow.document, content[i], 1);
            }
            outputWindow.document.write("</CODE>\n");
            outputWindow.document.write("</BODY></HTML>\n");

            outputWindow.document.close();
        }
        // ]]>
    </script>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <form>
        <textarea name="htmlcode" id="htmlCode" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea><br />
        <input type="button" value="Show me the DOM Tree" onclick="printDOMTree(document.getElementById('htmlCode')); return true;" />
        <br />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```